# How to set parameters in C# Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq-expressions

I am new to the expressions API in c#. Say I have an expression of two double parameters x and y. I would like to wrap this expression into another one where I can pass a double array instead of two arguments. I have tried the following (I am testing it in F#, hence the syntax)

```
let x = Expression.Parameter(typeof<double>,"x")
let y = Expression.Parameter(typeof<double>,"y")
let givenExpr = Expression.Add(x,y)

// I know that I can evaluate givenExpr as follows
let myLambda1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<double,double,double>>(givenExpr, [| x; y |]).Compile()
// and this works
myLambda1.Invoke(1.0,1.0)


// But if I instead want to pass x and y in an array and then "assign" them, this doesn't work
let inputArray = Expression.Parameter(typeof<double[]>,"inputs")
let result = Expression.Parameter(typeof<double>,"result")

let blockStatements = new List<Expression>()
blockStatements.Add( Expression.Assign(x,Expression.ArrayAccess(inputArray,Expression.Constant(0))) );
blockStatements.Add( Expression.Assign(y,Expression.ArrayAccess(inputArray,Expression.Constant(1))) );
blockStatements.Add( Expression.Assign(result, givenExpr) );

let block = Expression.Block( [| result |], blockStatements )

let arrayLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<double[],double>>(block, [|inputArray|]).Compile()
// This blows up 
arrayLambda.Invoke( [|1.0; 1.0|]) 
// with 
// System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'x' of type 'System.Double' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
//   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.Reference(ParameterExpression node, VariableStorageKind storage)
//   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.VariableBinder.VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) ....
```

Clearly, I am not being able to bind the values to the parameters but I don't know how to fix this. Any hints/suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks

**EDIT:** Basically what I want to achieve is to wrap a given function (e.g. Foo below) of n variables so that the wrapped function instead takes a single argument of type double[]. For plain methods I could do this as follows (example for 2 arguments)

```
double Foo( double x, double y);

double WrappedFoo( double [] args ){
    double x = args[0];
    double y = args[1];
    return Foo( x, y );
}
```

I am thinking of an expression as basically a function body (this might be incorrect!). So instead of Foo( double x, double y) say I am given an input expression (let's call it Foo_Expression) which I know has two parameters. I would like to wrap this expression in another one (the equivalent of WrappedFoo above) so that the new expression takes a single double array argument and then distributes those arguments to make a call to Foo_Expression. I am not sure if I can do this with expressions.

Comment: I am using F# only for testing. I intend to implement in C#. I should have made the title .NET rather than C#. Sorry.

Comment: Why not `double WrappedFoo(double[] args) { return Foo(args[0], args[1]); }`? You don't really need variables for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in normal C# code, variables in `Expression`s have to be declared. In the [overload of `Block` that you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324074), the first parameter lists the declared variables. So, you declare `result`, but not `x` or `y`.

It works in your first version, because there `x` and `y` are parameters, not local variables.

So, the fix is:

```
let block = Expression.Block( [| x; y; result |], blockStatements )
```

This works, but mostly by accident. You don't say that `result` is the value that should be returned, the actual returned value is of the last expression (`Expression`s are more like F# than C# in this regard).

So, the code with the fix would be equivalent to:

```
double WrappedFoo(double[] inputs)
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double result;

    x = inputs[0];
    y = inputs[1];
    return (result = Foo(x, y));
}
```

To get code more like the one you described, get rid of the `result` variable and change the last statement to just the expression you want to return:

```
blockStatements.Add(givenExpr)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I find it slightly counter intuitive that whereas in the regular C# code above, the variable names obviously don't have to match the parameter names, the expressions version is matching the local variables by name to the parameters of the givenExpr. In any case, very happy it works!

Comment: @user3727133 I don't understand what are you saying. In `Expression`s, parameters and variables are never matched by name, they are matched by reference of the `ParameterExpression` object.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters `x` and `y` are compiled in your previous lambda, and are not passed into the second `Expression.Lambda` call, but it doesn't seem like you want that anyway, because then you'd have an expressions with a method signature like `method(double[], double, double)`.  You likely wanted to define an additional `x2` and `y2` as locals which you could then pass as parameters to your first compiled lambda.

It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, if you clarify I might be able to help further.  Sometimes, it helps me to write the functions out how I want them to behave, and then convert them to the expression from that.